# get value of radio button using jQuery and php

Tags: php, jquery

I want to get the value clicked in radio button.

This is my code:

```
<ul class="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="accordion" id="clicks">
        <?php
        foreach ($preguntas['preguntas'] as $row)
        {
            $opciones = $pregunta->opciones($row[0]);
        ?>


            <li>
                <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="material-icons">question_answer</i><?php echo utf8_encode($row[2]); ?></div>

                <div class="collapsible-body">

                    <?php foreach ($opciones as $opcion){ ?>
                            <p class="left-align" id="options">
                                <input class="with-gap" name="pregunta_<?php echo utf8_encode($row[0]); ?>" type="radio" id="opcion_<?php echo utf8_encode($opcion[0]); ?><?php echo $row[0] ?>" value="<?php echo $opcion[0]; ?>" />
                                <label for="opcion_<?php echo $opcion[0]; ?><?php echo utf8_encode($row[0]); ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($opcion[2]); ?></label>
                            </p>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

I need to get the value of this input id="opcion_..."

```
<p class="left-align" id="options">
  <input class="with-gap" name="pregunta_<?php echo utf8_encode($row[0]); ?>" type="radio" id="opcion_<?php echo utf8_encode($opcion[0]); ?><?php echo $row[0] ?>" value="<?php echo $opcion[0]; ?>" />
  <label for="opcion_<?php echo $opcion[0]; ?><?php echo utf8_encode($row[0]); ?>"><?php echo utf8_encode($opcion[2]); ?></label>
</p>
```

The problem is name and id is changing, it's not the same 
Any idea?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery selector for part of attribute `$("[attribute^='value']")` like this:

```js
$("[id^='opcion_']").click(function(){
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <label><input name="pregunta_xxx" type="radio" id="opcion_123" value="123">radio for 123</label>
 <label><input name="pregunta_xxx" type="radio" id="opcion_456" value="456">radio for 456</label>
```